# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display current temperature of Halifax city using api key. But when I run the the code it throws error 'Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component'.

Below is my code which is used to display the current temperature from api.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const getWetherDetails = (cityName) => {
        if (!cityName) return
        const apiURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Halifax + "&appid=" + apiKey
        axios.get(apiURL).then((res) => {
            console.log("response", res.data)
            setData(res.data)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("err", err)
        })
    }
    
    
    
    const apiKey = "f56f24967aaf51182d1d4df628297c6d"
    const [inputCity, setInputCity] = useState("")
    export class Counter extends Component {
      static displayName = Counter.name;
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { currentCount: 0 };
        this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);
      }
        
      incrementCounter() {
        this.setState({
          currentCount: this.state.currentCount + 1
        });
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
                
                <br />
                <br />
                <img src="E:\\MCDA\\vs react\\Project1\\Project1\\Capture.PNG"/><br />
                <br />
                <h2><b>I live in Surat.</b></h2><br />
                <br />
                <p>Surat is a city located in Gujarat in India. It is also known as Diamond hub.
                   Surat is also know for its textile market.</p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <img src="E:\\MCDA\\vs react\\Project1\\Project1\\weather.png" /><br />
                <p>- &deg;C</p>
                <h6 className="weathorTemp">{((data?.main?.temp) - 273.15).toFixed(2)}°C</h6>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try add the const [data, setData] = useState({}) in the functional component, useState hook is not allowed write out the components

Comment: @RavitejaV So do I have to make a function inside the class?

Comment: hooks are allowed to use inside the functional component only, but hooks are not allowed to use it in the class components

Comment: @RavitejaV So is there any other way I can fetch data from that api? Since I already have class. ....How do i modify my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

hooks are only allowed inside functional component. you are trying to mix both (class and function component)

make it functional component or either use setState of class component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const apiKey = "f56f24967aaf51182d1d4df628297c6d"
export class Counter extends Component {
    static displayName = Counter.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { currentCount: 0, data: {}, inputCity: "" };
        this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);
    }

    incrementCounter() {
        this.setState({
            currentCount: this.state.currentCount + 1
        });
    }

    getWetherDetails = (cityName) => {
        if (!cityName) return
        const apiURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Halifax + "&appid=" + apiKey
        axios.get(apiURL).then((res) => {
            console.log("response", res.data)
            this.setState({ re.data })
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("err", err)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state
        return (
            <div>

                <br />
                <br />
                <img src="E:\\MCDA\\vs react\\Project1\\Project1\\Capture.PNG" /><br />
                <br />
                <h2><b>I live in Surat.</b></h2><br />
                <br />
                <p>Surat is a city located in Gujarat in India. It is also known as Diamond hub.
                    Surat is also know for its textile market.</p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <img src="E:\\MCDA\\vs react\\Project1\\Project1\\weather.png" /><br />
                <p>- &deg;C</p>
                <h6 className="weathorTemp">{((data?.main?.temp) - 273.15).toFixed(2)}°C</h6>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since hooks are allowed in the functional components only, we can use state for storing the required data in class based components.

I have updated the code according to the class based component.

please use the debounce while making api call, which will increase efficiency of making api calls.

> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
> // Move these keys to config file
> const apiKey = "f56f24967aaf51182d1d4df628297c6d" 
>
> export class WetherDetails extends Component {
> static displayName = Counter.name;
>
> constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     this.state = { 
>         currentCount: 0,
>         data: {},
>         inputCity: ""
>     };
>     this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);
>     this.getWetherDetails = this.getWetherDetails.bind(this);
> }
>
> incrementCounter() {
>     this.updateState({ currentCount: this.state.currentCount + 1 });
> }
>
> updateState(newstate) {
>     this.setState((prevState) => ({
>         ...prevState,
>         newstate,
>     }));
> }
>
> getWetherDetails(cityName) {
>     if (!cityName) return
>     const apiURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=" + cityName + "&appid=" + apiKey
>     axios
>         .get(apiURL)
>         .then((res) => {
>             console.log("response", res.data)
>             this.updateState(res.data)
>         }).catch((err) => {
>             console.log("err", err)
>         })
> }
>
> updateCity(e) {
>     this.updateState({ inputCity: e?.target?.value })
>     // use debounce to call the getWetherDetails
>     //
> }
>
> render() {
> return (
>     <div>
>         <input type={"text"} onChange={this.updateCity} />
>         <br />
>         <br />
>         <img src="E:\\MCDA\\vs react\\Project1\\Project1\\Capture.PNG"/><br />
>         <br />
>         <h2><b>I live in Surat.</b></h2><br />
>         <br />
>         <p>Surat is a city located in Gujarat in India. It is also known as Diamond hub.
>             Surat is also know for its textile market.</p>
>         <br />
>         <br />
>         <img src="E:\\MCDA\\vs react\\Project1\\Project1\\weather.png" /><br />
>         <p>- &deg;C</p>
>         <h6 className="weathorTemp">{((data?.main?.temp) - 273.15).toFixed(2)}°C</h6>
>     </div>
> );
> } }
> ```